# Database connection session variable

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a database class which I would like to optimise by storing the connection in a session variable and then checking this connection exists and using it everytime the class is required to connect, such as with a query function call.
Are there any security implications on doing this.

The aim would be reduce processing time as the site uses a lot of ajax database connections, so to avoid constant reconnection overhead

Comment: Why? Not sure what you expect to gain from doing this! What do you think you will gain?

Comment: The API looks after pooling and reusing connections assuming it is configured to do that

Comment: The aim would be reduce processing time as the site uses a lot of ajax database connections, so to avoid constant reconnection overhead

Comment: Like I said in comment 2. The API looks after that for you

Comment: I wouldn't store any DB connection in $_SESSION -> if not done properly, you'll leave a door open into your database. There is next-to-no overhead for connecting to the DB